# Mysql Pivot with Max Clause

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I have a table named **table_one** as shown below:

| fk_tbl_id | types | values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | type_a | value_a |
| 10 | type_b | value_b |
| 20 | type_a | value_c |
| 20 | type_b | value_d |

Expected output as shown below:

| fk_tbl_id | type_a | type_b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | value_a | value_b |
| 20 | value_c | value_d |

Attempt #1:

```
SELECT 
    fk_tbl_id, 
    CASE types WHEN ‘type_a’ THEN values END AS type_a,
    CASE types WHEN ‘type_b’ THEN values END AS type_b
FROM table_one
GROUP BY fk_tbl_id;
```

I got the result from attempt #1 as shown below which is not what I want

| fk_tbl_id | type_a | type_b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | value_a | null |
| 20 | value_c | null |

Attempt #2:

```
SELECT 
    fk_tbl_id, 
    MAX(CASE types WHEN ‘type_a’ THEN values END) AS type_a,
    MAX(CASE types WHEN ‘type_b’ THEN values END) AS type_b
FROM table_one
GROUP BY fk_tbl_id;
```

I got my expected result from attempt #2 but I don’t understand why adding the max clause will do the work.
Appreciate if anyone could describe this to me.

Comment: 1st query is not correct. Simply enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY..

Comment: max is an aggregation function query would work equally well with min